# Is it possible to convert Option<Result<T, E>> to a Result<Option<T>, E> without using match?

Tags: rust, option-type, rust-result

My first thought is to `map` the `Option`, but I can't use `try!` from inside of the closure. The `match` statement looks unnecessary, but I can't figure out how to simplify it.

```
fn example<T, E>(val: Option<Result<T, E>>) -> Result<Option<T>, E> {
    Ok(match val {
        Some(v) => Some(v?),
        None => None
    })
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In Rust 1.33, [`transpose()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.transpose) is stable, so you can just call it:

```
fn main() {
    let x: Result<Option<i32>, ()> = Ok(Some(5));
    let y: Option<Result<i32, ()>> = Some(Ok(5));
    assert_eq!(x, y.transpose());
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`Option::map_or()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map_or):

```
val.map_or(Ok(None), |v| v.map(Some))
```

Comment: And the reverse can be done by `val.map(|v| v.map(Ok)).unwrap_or_else(|e| Some(Err(e)))`