# Unwrap Result inside Optional

Tags: rust

Is there a canonical way to convert `Option<Result<T>>` to `Result<Option<T>>`?

```
fn optres_to_resopt<T>(optres: Option<Result<T>>) -> Result<Option<T>> {
    if let Some(res) = optres {
        match res {
            Ok(v) => Ok(Some(v)),
            Err(e) => Err(e),
        }
    } else {
        Ok(None)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is [Option::transpose](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.transpose):

```
fn optres_to_resopt<T>(optres: Option<Result<T>>) -> Result<Option<T>> {
    optres.transpose()
}
```

And BTW, the [implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.40.0/src/core/option.rs.html#1172-1178) is basically your function:

```
pub fn transpose(self) -> Result<Option<T>, E> {
    match self {
        Some(Ok(x)) => Ok(Some(x)),
        Some(Err(e)) => Err(e),
        None => Ok(None),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would definitely use `transpose`(from the approved answer) but as an exercise here is a different version of implementation:

```rust
fn optres_to_resopt<T, E>(optres: Option<Result<T, E>>) -> Result<Option<T>, E> {
    optres.map_or(Ok(None), |x| Ok(Some(x?)))
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=17966c3fbb60baf92555435ede58ff8a)

Since `Result` also has a `transpose` method too, it is easy to revert it back. As an alternative we can apply the same approach in this problem too:

```rust
fn resopt_optres<T, E>(resopt: Result<Option<T>, E>) -> Option<Result<T, E>> {
    resopt
        .map(|x| Some(Ok(x?)))
        .unwrap_or_else(|x| Some(Err(x)))
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=63e8a31e63466532457cd6d2cd3a4213)

**Note :** The idea in here is `map_or`(or `unwap_or_else`) has ability to change the enclosing type with a generic type.

Comment: I like this answer, but just for your interest, you can simplify those a bit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43166454/365102

Comment: @MateenUlhaq aah, i didn’t want to use closure inside a closure, but i guess i’ve totally forgot that we can use tuples as a closure argument, thanks ^^